# Load and bind template laravel to save into database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to load a **blade** template and bind with some values and later save that html string into a database, how can I do that?

I creating a queue model to send some mails but I want my workers just send mails not bind or fetch data to bind mails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the view like normal, but then render it instead of returning it:

```
$html = View::make('mytemplate', compact('somedata'))->render();
```

From the [View API documentation](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/View/View.html#method_render):

> render(Closure $callback = null)
>
> Get the string contents of the view.